# consulta para el uso de express-jwt,error al leer datos ._id

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

estoy tomando un curso para aprender y en un ejercicio me da un error en el retorno del id de la base de datos, con lo cual no puedo seguir avanzando, he intentado buscar algun problema similar y no lo he encontrado y ahora pregunto por aqui si alguien me podria ayudar y explicar un poco donde se encuentra el error

no se si el codigo arroja error por el hecho de que se actualizaran las librerias estoy usando

Node.js v18.12.1
"bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"express-jwt": "^8.3.0",
"jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
"mongoose": "^6.8.2",

mi codigo

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { expressjwt: jwt1 } = require("express-jwt");
const User = require("./user");

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://usuario:********@ac-lyiyvgm-shard-00-00.vhh6fk8.mongodb.net:27017,ac-lyiyvgm-shard-00-01.vhh6fk8.mongodb.net:27017,ac-lyiyvgm-shard-00-02.vhh6fk8.mongodb.net:27017/miAuth?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-8dyx3l-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const validateJwt = jwt1({ secret: "secret", algorithms: 
["HS256"] });
const signToken = (_id) => jwt.sign({ _id }, "secret");

// endpoint de registro de usuario
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  console.log({ body });
  try {
    const isUser = await User.findOne({ email: body.email });
    if (isUser) {
      return res.status(403).send("Usuario ya existe");
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, salt);
    const user = await User.create({
      email: body.email,
      password: hashed,
      salt,
    });
    const signed = signToken(user._id);
    res.status(201).send({ signed });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

// endpoint de inicio de sesion
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: body.email });
    if (!user) {
      res.status(403).send("Usuario y/o contraseña invalido");
    } else {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(body.password, 
user.password);
      if (isMatch) {
        const signed = signToken(user._id);
        res.status(200).send(signed);
      } else {
        res.status(403).send("Usuario y/o contraseña 
invalido");
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

// middleware de validacion de los JsonWebToken
app.get(
  "/auth",
  validateJwt,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).end();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  },
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(req.user);
  }
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3000");
});
```

[image: imagen del error del codigo en consola]

Comment: ¿En qué ruta te da error?. Al parecer al hacer uso de la ruta `"/auth"`, el valor de `req.user` no estaría definido, por lo cual el mensaje de error que muestras. ¿Podrías explicar un poco más el proceso que estás intentado realizar para poder ayudarte?. Saludos

Comment: lo que intento hacer es ver y aprender a hacer una validacion de JsonWebToken, comprobar que el usuario existe y que retorne el id junto con el iat de la base de datos para de esta formadecidir si caduca el JsonWebYoken

utilizando un codigo mas sencillo me da un error diferente

app.get("/auth", validateJwt, (req, res, netx) => {
  console.log("user", req.user);
  res.status(200).send("ok");
});

utilixando ese codigo como middleware, me da un error de undefined, en lugar del otro error de que no puede leer las propiedades

Comment: Entiendo, trataré de darte una respuesta clara en cuanto pueda. Saludos